# Trigger the phone function by clicking the number once in the HTML

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios

I add `<a href=”tel://xxx”>xxx</a>` in the HTML.
I insert the HTML into the Xcode and use WKWebView to load the HTML.
Then run the Demo on my iPhone.
I must long press the `xxx` number to trigger An alert displayed modally for the app. The first button of the alert shows the text "Call XXX".
If I press the "Call XXX" button, then the iPhone will call.

[image].

In my opinion, the long press is not a friendly way to the user.
Is there a way to trigger the phone function by clicking the number once in the HTML.

One more thing, I will insert the HTML into the Android App.
In Android App, How to trigger the phone call by clicking the number.

Answer (score 0):

You should Override **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** method in your Webview Client and do whatever you want with that url.

```
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    //do something here
    return true;
   }
```